# Use localized icons for Q&A in left navigation menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, localization, icons, left-nav

On the recent update, we got icons next to items on the left navigation menu. All these icons are used for any SE sites. At the same time on localized sites, like SO in Russian, there are localized icons for Question and Answer.

> [image]

Could we please use such icons on left navigation as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. We were not using localized icons for non-English sites. This has been fixed and should now be live.

Comment: You're fast!!!!

Comment: Should the [Japanese SO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) also be changed or does it not really work that way between the alphabets? I realize it uses "Q" and "A" still for the icons across the JA.SO site, but _should it_?

Comment: @TimothyG. Correct, the Japanese site currently uses the Q and A icons already and so the left navigation matches, they do not have localized icons. The left navigation update did not include time for creating new icons unfortunately. Creating custom icons for Japanese SO would need to be a separate feature request as something we look into.